# How to separate emojies in string without spaces in LUA 5.1

Tags: string, split, lua, emoji, lua-5.1

I want to use split function of LUA 5.1 to split string of emoji characters without spaces and add space between ones, but I can't do it rightly. So I do it by this way, but it's wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

local text = "‍‍‍‍‍⌚↔"
for emoji in string.gmatch(text, "[%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*") do
    io.write(emoji .. " ")          
end
```

See in browser Firefox 65!

MY WRONG RESULT:                ⌚ ↔

WAITED RESULT:       ‍‍‍ ‍‍ ⌚ ↔

Comment: In other words, you want to insert commas between emojies?

Comment: Try `text = text:gsub("\226\128\141", ""):gsub("(.)([\194-\244])", "%1,%2")` The first gsub is needed to remove U+200D characters from your string

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I need to separate emojies any symbols.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I need to get compound emojies, don't split them into separate ones.

Comment: This sounds like an encoding mismatch between your terminal and/or editor.

Comment: @glennjackman no, it's damn compound emojies (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local text = "‍‍‍‍‍⌚↔"
for emoji in text
   :gsub("(.)([\194-\244])", "%1\0%2")
   :gsub("%z(\240\159\143[\187-\191])", "%1")
   :gsub("%z(\239\184[\128-\143])", "%1")
   :gsub("%z(\226\128\141)%z", "%1")
   :gmatch"%Z+" 
do
   print(emoji)
end
```

Comment: It's ok! but how to glue emojies with different colors (example:  +  = ) U+1F3FB  240 159 143 187;
U+1F3FC  240 159 143 188;
U+1F3FD  240 159 143 189;
U+1F3FE  240 159 143 190;
U+1F3FF  240 159 143 191;

Comment: I don't see any colored emojies on this SO page :-)  To glue emojies, just insert `"\226\128\141"` in between them.

Comment: Open page in the Browser Firefox 65.0.1 (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: @Dzmitry - Indeed, they are colored in new Firefox! FF60 is enough.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thanks for the answers. I'll try to modify it to solve my problem.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff well done! but it doesn't glue: ‍❤️‍‍ -> ‍❤ ‍. What part of the expression do gluing?

Comment: @Dzmitry - Updated.